How to Display Item Quantity Based on Product Selection in Laravel 11?
How to display the quantity of items from the 'item_amount' column when a product name is selected from the 'item_name' selector in Laravel 11, based on the data in the database?
Database



id
item_code
item_name
item_amount




1
001
Pena
67


2
003
Palu
45



item.blade.php
    <!-- another code -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="item_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Pilih Barang</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih Barang</option>
                @foreach($item as $item)
                    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->item_name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="item-amount" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Jumlah Barang Tersedia</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            {{ $item->item_amount }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- another code -->

DemandController
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $demand = Demand::select('*');

            return DataTables::of($demand)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                    $edit_btn = '<button ' .
                    ' class="btn btn-info" ' .
                    ' onclick="editItem(' . $row->id . ')">Ubah' .
                    '</button> ';
                    $del_btn = '<button ' .
                    ' class="btn btn-danger" ' .
                    ' onclick="deleteItem(' . $row->id . ')">Hapus' .
                    '</button> ';
                    return $edit_btn . $del_btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }

        $item = Item::all();
        $item_amount = Item::select('item_amount')->get();
        return view('demand', compact('item', 'item_amount'));
    }

Models/Item
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Item extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;

        protected $table = 'item';

        protected $fillable = [
            'item_code', 'item_name', 'item_amount', 'item_unit', 'item_department'
        ];

        public function supplies()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Supply::class);
        }

        public function demands()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Demand::class);
        }
    }

Models/Demand.php
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Demand extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table = 'demand';
        protected $fillable = [
            'item_id', 'user_id', 'sent_out', 'is_verify'
        ];

        public function item()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
        }

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }
    }

routes/web.php
    <?php

    use App\Http\Controllers\DemandController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\ItemController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\RecruitmentsController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\SupplyController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::resource('recruitments', RecruitmentsController::class);
    Route::resource('item', ItemController::class);
    Route::resource('demand', DemandController::class);
    Route::resource('supply', SupplyController::class);
    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);

Problem
My problem is not updating in real-time, not matching the database content
I want the 'item_amount' value to automatically update in real-time when selecting a product name from a dropdown selector, using Laravel and AJAX for modal.

add change event to item_name in js, in the call back send an ajax/axios request to the server with item_name, query the items table, fetch the amount for the item and in the success of ajax/axios display the amount.
